# Windows microphone has some weird distortion over it

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

I'm a Windows 7 user, I have a USB headset that has been working perfectly fine for some time until recently. Now the microphone adds some kind of distortion to the sound. And another weird thing is, it's added a microphone level option to the headset in the speaker part, that will allow me to hear the microphone, with no distortion, but as this is not an input device, other software won't take that source.

Screenshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrBNW.jpg).

What I am asking you, is how can I get a clean output to the recording devices tab, thanks.

Comment: Have you gone to the vendor site and update the drivers?  Your driver you have might not co-exist well with some of the recent windows updates that have been done.  Another cause could be the program being used has a problem.....or finally you could have some type of hardware clash or hardware failure.  You are going to have to do some investigation of your own here.